# get raw_input data from main

Tags: python-2.7, raw-input

I'm new in python and have not much experience in programming also.

I have this code in my main file:

```
def user_input():
   import re
   name_check = re.compile(r"[^A-Za-z\s. ]")
   print("Please enter name input: ")
   name = raw_input("> ")
   return name

def test():



if __name__ =="__main__":
   user_input()
   test()
```

How can I get the user_input parameter in order to process it in others child modules?
I'm trying to import the main module to the child file module but it doesn't work. 
This is my program structure:

```
/main
  __init__.py  
  main.py
  /child
    __init__.py    
    child1.py
    child2.py
```

I need to pass user_input data to child1.py. When I do importing main:

```
from main.main import user_input
```

I've got error message:

```
No module named main.main
```

Any comments would be much appreciate.

Cheers

Comment: at your end of `user_input()` function add code `return name` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code takes in input through `raw_input()` in the `user_input()` function, and then uses `return` to return it. In our `print_input()` function, we take *in* the input. In our `main()` function, we assign the return value from `user_input()` to `name`, and then pass it into `print_input()`.

```
def user_input():
    name = raw_input("Please enter name input:\n> "
    return name

def print_input(name):
    print "Hello", name

def main():
    name = user_input()
    print_input(name)

if __name__ =="__main__":
    main()
```

## Edit

`main.py`:

```
def user_input():
    name = raw_input("Please enter name input:\n> "
    return name

def print_input(name):
    print "Hello", name

def main():
    name = user_input()
    print_input(name)
```

To call a function from here do the following:

```
>>> from main import user_input, print_input
>>> 
>>> print_input(user_input())
Please enter name input:
> aj8uppal
Hello aj8uppal
>>>
```